# Build failed to run VS Test Runner

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I need help to troubleshoot the root cause of this build error during Step "Run VS Test Runner"

> TFS 2013 Update 4, VS 2015   Build Def uses
>   ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml   msBuild Parameters /tv:14.0
>   <..................>
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install VS2013 or [Test Agent for VS2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750) on build server should fix this issue.

Comment: Tried to avoid this step, but the Jasmine UI Test would required installing VS 2013 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0` to your MSBuild arguments.

Comment: Is that a custom  build template?